UDP mDNS on MacOS using C, Rust, JVM - Packets not being received
I'll do my best to keep it short.

While implementing multicast DNS protocols, I'm unable to listen to multicast DNS in either C or rust (However in JVM it works perfectly fine)
I am watching network using Wireshark
I've tried disabling firewall, disabling certain features of the firewall, none work.
Network has IPv6 enabled

Question is: What could be the cause of being unable to receive multicast packets on non virtualised code (Non JVM)
OS:

MacOS 14.4 (ARM)
Windows 11 (ARM ~ VM on Mac)

Rust code: (Does not work)
use std::net::UdpSocket;

fn main() {
    let udp = UdpSocket::bind("[::]:0").expect("Unable to bind!");
    println!("{}", udp.local_addr().unwrap());
    udp.connect("ff02::fb%en0:5353").unwrap();
    let mut buffer = [0; 65000];
    let size = udp.recv(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("Data received: {}", size);
}

Kotlin (JVM) code: Works
import java.net.DatagramPacket
import java.net.MulticastSocket

fun main() {
    val port = 5353 // Multicast port
    val socket = MulticastSocket(port)
    val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
    val packet = DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.size)
    println("UDP server listening for multicast packets on ${socket.localSocketAddress}")
    while (true) {
        socket.receive(packet)
        val receivedData = packet.data.copyOf(packet.length)
        val receivedMessage = String(receivedData)
        println("Received message: $receivedMessage")
    }
}

C code: (Does not work)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1024 // Maximum message length

int main() {
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    char buffer[MAX_LEN + 1];
    int bytes_received;

    // Create a UDP socket
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0) {
        perror("socket creation failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    // Fill in the address structure
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Listen on any interface
    addr.sin_port = htons(12345); // Choose any port number you like

    // Bind the socket to the address
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Specify the multicast group to join
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr("224.0.0.251"); // Multicast group address
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Listen on any interface

    // Join the multicast group
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Receive multicast messages
    while (1) {
        bytes_received = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, MAX_LEN, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if (bytes_received < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom failed");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        buffer[bytes_received] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received data
        printf("Received message: %s\n", buffer);
    }

    // Close the socket
    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}


Is the %en0 in the address given to Rust's UdpSocket::connect deliberate?  I don't think it's valid.

Yessir, it provides information for routing to host (platform specific i'd assume since this was only allowed on macos - tested with netcat as well).

According to the RFC, the zone ID, %en0, is only valid for IPv6 Link-Local addressing (fe80::/10). "To limit this risk, implementations MUST NOT allow use of this format except for well-defined usages, such as sending to link-local addresses under prefix fe80::/10. At the time of writing, this is the only well-defined usage known."

Interesting... Any idea what could be the reason I can't listen to mDNS with rust and c?

the c version above receives ipv4 packets on joined group, about rust and java - no idea, that code in different languages is not equal

@yvs2014 what OS are you testing this on? On my MacOS the C code doesn't receive any packets.

on linux: sending something multicast to written ipv4addr:port and receiving that

the other thing what and how you test that tho

Well the thing I'm measuring this against is seeing other traffic on wireshark sent by other devices (spotify, homepods and such), but none of them come to the program with above code (except Kotlin).

"other traffic" it's too vague. In the examples in rust and kotlin I cannot even see multicast group joining, do you suppose that there done implicitly?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I answered on a similar question (also posted by me trying to clarify things more): mDNS / Bonjour / UDP 5353 Port reusability
